# FeatureUnion : Sklearn FeatureUnion does not allows fit params

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

FeatureUnion is not able to fit. The last line of the following code fit() throws error as:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

iris = load_iris()    
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
selection = SelectKBest(k=1)
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", pca), ("univ_select", selection)])
svm = SVC(kernel="linear")

pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features), ("svm", svm)])
pipeline.fit (X, y, features__univ_select__k=2)
```

Error Thrown:

```
TypeError: fit_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'univ_select__k'
```

Comment: Though this code is not actually useful, but it exposes a real life use case of passing a pipeline__parameter when FeatureUnion is involved. Actually I am getting this error in a related code which is not exactly this one. Hence, I need to conform the behavior of fit() when FeatureUnion is involved.

Comment: Please do *not* use the comments space to add this kind of info - edit & update your post instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `features__univ_select__k=2` is **not** used in `fit`; on the other hand, it is simply not necessary here.

If you are following the feature union [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_feature_union.html) in the scikit-learn docs (as you seem to be), you should notice that there it is used as an argument in `param_grid`, and not in `fit`.

But here you don't perform any parameter grid search; and since you have already defined that

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
selection = SelectKBest(k=1)
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", pca), ("univ_select", selection)])
```

there is not any other "choice" for the number of features to be used, hence you should not use any `features__univ_select__k=2` argument. Simply giving

```
pipeline.fit (X, y)
```

does the job:

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('features', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=None,
       transformer_list=[('pca', PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=2, random_state=None,
  svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)), ('univ_select', SelectKBest(k=1, score_func=<function f_classif at 0x000000000808AD08>))],
       tran...r', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False))])
```

Comment: I understand, u are right. But that still doesn't answers my question. Actually I am getting this error in a related code which is not exactly this one. Hence, I need to confirm the behavior of fit() when FeatureUnion is involved.

Comment: @sapthrishi007 But here FeatureUnion *is* involved indeed. And, in any case, `features__univ_select__k` is *not* supposed to be used in `fit`, so the actual answer to your question is that you use a wrong syntax (updated answer to highlight this).